# allocating 16GB in one single array, malloc fails silently

Tags: arrays, memory-management, malloc

I am working on very large datasets. I am trying to allocate 16GB in one single array

for some reason I don't know, if I try to access the position (let's say) "600 million"  I get that this position isn't accessible and I get a segmentation fault error in run time.

Does anyone know why this happens?

my architecture is 64 bit, therefore it should be possible to address 16billion of addresses, or at least this is what I think.

my call is:

`int* array = (int*) malloc(sizeof(int)* 1000000000 * 4);`

thank you all!

@ ScottChamberlain, @Sanhdrir: it fails silently because it doesn't return a NULL pointer. As you may have noticed this array represents a matrix. before allocating it in this way I tried to allocate it with a pointer to pointers. this required more space in memory (8billions of bytes more) in order to save the address of each pointer. In this way I got my program killed, while now I don't, but when I try to access some addresses I get segmentation fault.

**edit** if i allocate 10 blocks of 160 millions (or even more) i don't get any error and the memory is allocated. the problem is in allocating one big block. my question now becomes: is there a way to overcome this limit?

**edit2** @Sanhadrin your hypothesis are all correct, except for the fact that I use gcc.
I am reporting here the contents of the /proc/meminfo/ file

`MemTotal:       198049828 kB
MemFree:        113419800 kB
Buffers:          153064 kB
Cached:          5689680 kB
SwapCached:       124780 kB
Active:         73880720 kB
Inactive:        8998084 kB
Active(anon):   70843644 kB
Inactive(anon):  6192548 kB
Active(file):    3037076 kB
Inactive(file):  2805536 kB
Unevictable:           0 kB
Mlocked:               0 kB
SwapTotal:      201273340 kB
SwapFree:       164734524 kB
Dirty:                 0 kB
Writeback:             0 kB
AnonPages:      76915376 kB
Mapped:            16376 kB
Shmem:                72 kB
Slab:             190352 kB
SReclaimable:     124660 kB
SUnreclaim:        65692 kB
KernelStack:        3432 kB
PageTables:       259828 kB
NFS_Unstable:          0 kB
Bounce:                0 kB
WritebackTmp:          0 kB
CommitLimit:    300298252 kB
Committed_AS:   160461824 kB
VmallocTotal:   34359738367 kB
VmallocUsed:      733424 kB
VmallocChunk:   34258351392 kB
HardwareCorrupted:     0 kB
AnonHugePages:         0 kB
HugePages_Total:       0
HugePages_Free:        0
HugePages_Rsvd:        0
HugePages_Surp:        0
Hugepagesize:       2048 kB
DirectMap4k:      195520 kB
DirectMap2M:    37507072 kB
DirectMap1G:    163577856 kB`

Comment: which programming language c/c++ or others?

Comment: what the stack size (ulimit -s)?

Comment: But is your application itself 64-bit? Depending on platform, compiler, and options, you could be creating a 32-bit executable. Beyond that, do you actually have 16GB of free addressable RAM?

You said that "malloc() fails silently". Are you actually checking whether the result of malloc is NULL, and checking errno to see the reason for failure? Or were you expecting it to crash?

Comment: @Sanhadrin i have 16GB or memory, if i hadn't i think my program would get killed. the result of malloc is not NULL, i check that, how do i check errno? "segmentation fault" is the only error i get when i try to access some address which should be accessible though

Comment: @almasshaikh i'm programming in c++, but i use c calls to make it more efficient, i don't think the size of the stack is very important since i'm using the heap, am i right?

Comment: If `array` is not NULL then how do you know it failed? Please explain more on what errors you get in your program by [editing your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/26451253/edit).

Comment: @Sergio Do you have 16GB of *free*, allocatable memory? What OS (Linux's memory allocation strategy means that may not return NULL, but did not allocate the memory - read 'man malloc')? What compiler? What compiler settings? Why would you think your program would get killed if it tried to allocate more than 16GB of memory - that won't kill it, only accessing it will, which it is. Checking errno is typically only required if malloc returns NULL but may return a correct underlying error regardless - not sure.

Comment: @Sergio Finally, it's highly unlikely you need 16GB of allocated memory in RAM - there's almost certainly a better strategy. I'm guessing you're doing it for "performance" (since you say you're using C calls instead of C++ for the same reason..) but given that you're opening yourself up to major paging issues unless you're using a high-performance computer that's specifically tuned for this kind of usage, there's certainly a better way that involves only keeping a portion of data in memory at any one time.

Comment: What's important is that did you make sure to set the target as 64 bit? Running a 64-bit system doesn't necessarily mean the output is also 64-bit because it can even a different architecture's executable. By default some compilers will produce 32-bit executables. Moreover you can allocate 10 1.6GB blocks on a 4GB RAM system if the memory allocator uses lazy allocation and you don't write anything to it

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc i used g++ option -m64 in order to have a 64-bit executable

Comment: @Sergio Since you're using g++, I assume you're using Linux. Like I said, have you read the man entry for malloc()? How much RAM do you actually have installed, how much is visible in Linux, and how much is free?

Comment: Or a shortcut: what value is in /proc/sys/vm/overcommit_memory?

Answer (score 1):

The amount of information makes this difficult to answer for sure, but it seems:

- You're on an x86-64 architecture
- You may be running Linux
- You have at least 16GB of RAM, but it's uncertain whether you have over 16GB of *free* RAM
- You're compiling with gcc with settings configured to create a 64-bit binary
- Your calls to malloc() are returning a seemingly valid (non-null) pointer
- Indexing into that memory may result in a segmentation fault

If you read malloc's man page, it says:

> Notes
>
> By default, Linux follows an optimistic memory allocation strategy. This means that when malloc() returns non-NULL there is no guarantee that the memory really is available. In case it turns out that the system is out of memory, one or more processes will be killed by the OOM killer. For more information, see the description of /proc/sys/vm/overcommit_memory and /proc/sys/vm/oom_adj in proc(5), and the Linux kernel source file Documentation/vm/overcommit-accounting.

following up by reading man proc, it states:

> /proc/sys/vm/overcommit_memory
>                 This file contains the kernel virtual memory accounting mode.
>                 Values are:

```
                 0: heuristic overcommit (this is the default)
                 1: always overcommit, never check
                 2: always check, never overcommit

          In mode 0, calls of mmap(2) with MAP_NORESERVE are not
          checked, and the default check is very weak, leading to the
          risk of getting a process "OOM-killed".  Under Linux 2.4, any
          nonzero value implies mode 1.
```

So, depending on the setting of overcommit_memory, malloc() may return a valid pointer even when the requested space is not available, in the belief that by the time you use that much memory, other processes will have been terminated, freeing up the needed space. That's not the case here because you're using it immediately - meaning you actually don't have 16GB of free space to work with in the first place. Further:

> ```
>          In mode 2 (available since Linux 2.6), the total virtual
>           address space that can be allocated (CommitLimit in
>           /proc/meminfo) is calculated as
> ```

```
              CommitLimit = (total_RAM - total_huge_TLB) *
                            overcommit_ratio / 100 + total_swap

          where:

               *  total_RAM is the total amount of RAM on the system;

               *  total_huge_TLB is the amount of memory set aside for
                  huge pages;

               *  overcommit_ratio is the value in
                  /proc/sys/vm/overcommit_ratio; and

               *  total_swap is the amount of swap space.

          For example, on a system with 16GB of physical RAM, 16GB of
          swap, no space dedicated to huge pages, and an
          overcommit_ratio of 50, this formula yields a CommitLimit of
          24GB.

          Since Linux 3.14, if the value in
          /proc/sys/vm/overcommit_kbytes is nonzero, then CommitLimit is
          instead calculated as:

              CommitLimit = overcommit_kbytes + total_swap
```

So, at the very least, you can do a better job of preventing it from overcommitting, so that malloc() fails as expected - but the underlying issue is that you're asking for an extremely large amount of space that you seemingly don't have. You can check /proc/meminfo to see how much is actually free at any one time, and other memory statistics, to see what the issue is and what your real limits are.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to allocate memory blocks of very large sizes, you should use your operating system services to map virtual memory to the process; not malloc().

If you have any hope of allocating 16GB on your system, you need to do it that way.